# Why is my screen flickering when I plug in my second monitor (which is a TV?)

Tags: monitor, graphics-card

I have two monitors right now, one is a 4k UHD TV.

When I have the display "Extend these displays" rather than "Show only on 1" (1 is the monitor, not the TV) the screen flickers horrendously. When I do show only 1, the screen stops flickering. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. It was because the monitor was changing the refresh rate to 60hz instead of the 144hz default or the 165hz overclock I set it to. Changing the refresh rate in my nvidia control panel back to 165hz fixed the screen flickering.